# Await for server response PostAsJsonAsync

Tags: c#, winforms

So, i have this code and I want to freeze the form while the server hasn't responded.

`var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, _savedClient);`

What should i do?

```
        try
        {
            frmMainForm._idErro = 1;
            using (var client = ReturnHTTP.HTTP())
            {
                frmMainForm._idErro = 11;
                var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, _savedClient);
                //MessageBox.Show();
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(1000, "Informação", "Cliente atualizado com sucesso", ToolTipIcon.Info);
                    notifyIcon.Visible = true;
                    frmMainForm._idErro = 3;
                    frmMainForm._tableContract.Clear();
                    List<Client> client_status = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Client>>();
                    frmMainForm._tableContract = ConvertDataTable.ToDataTable(client_status);
                    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

                    DadosParaEmail();

                    _gravou = true;
                    Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    string a = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
                    Error.saveErro(a, result);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string a = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
            string exc = ex.Message;
            Error.saveErro(a, exc);
        }
```

Comment: then just remove async/await.

Comment: var response = client.PostAsJson(url, _savedClient);

Comment: i am getting a error here `if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)` if i do that.

Comment: can you provide the full code of your method in above question?

Comment: was that what you wanted?

Comment: what error message you get?

Comment: Isma already posted what i need. But thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to block the current thread while waiting for a response you can try the following:

```
var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, _savedClient).Result;
```

Comment: thanks, was something like that that i was looking for.